# How to show 2 record from 3 or more record?

Tags: mysql

Ex : I have mysql data from table times:

```
2020-06-09 08:09
2020-06-09 08:10
2020-06-09 08:10
2020-06-09 14:29
2020-06-09 14:29
```

I use..

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM times;
```

But this query show 3 record...

```
2020-06-09 08:09
2020-06-09 08:10
2020-06-09 14:29
```

How i can show 2 record from times table?

```
2020-06-09 08:09
2020-06-09 14:29
```

Comment: Give LIMIT a try,

Comment: `limit` 2 and decide which ones you want to select first

Comment: You need to show more of your code and explain better what you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DISTINCT Selects only unique values all rows but 2020-06-09 14:29 & 2020-06-09 08:10 will be shown with this query.

If you use LIMIT 2 the result will be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM times LIMIT 2;

2020-06-09 08:09
2020-06-09 08:10
```

I think you need to explain better what you really want to do?!

If you like the two first records from your table use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM times LIMIT 2;
```

If you like the lowest date first.. use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM times LIMIT 2 ORDER BY times ASC;
```

**UPDATE**

From your comment i guess you have two times? or.. another column wich tells if it was check_in or check_out?!

```
SELECT MIN(times) WHERE in_out = "in";
SELECT MIN(check_in), MAX(check_out) ?
```

I'm only guessing. I need to see more from your table structure.

Comment: they also need to figure out which two to preferentially select

Comment: i want to select first check_in and last check_out.. If check_in or check_out have some data, i just want to select 1 check_in and 1 check_out..

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless